# Is there a reason not to use a custom "comment" attribute?

Tags: html

Is there a reason not to do the following?

```
<div comment="start display area">
     ...
</div>
```

I like to add notes, and this seems like an ideal way to do it.

I know I could do this as well:

```
<!--Start display area-->
<div">
     ...
</div>
```

The first syntax just seems cleaner to me.  The issue I run into with `<!--` Is that sometimes, I do want to comment out an area of HTML for debugging purposes.  That doesn't work when there are comment strings in there.

I found this much earlier discussion on it:  https://www.w3.org/XML/2000/04schema-hacking/comment-test.html

Comment: from my understanding it's just W3C which doesn't like it. i read multiple articles that perfect W3C valid html is not faster or better for SEO than pages with some errors in them and undefined attributes which aren't `data-*` (like you `comment` attribute) counts as an error to them. you can still use something like `document.querySelectorAll("#test")[0].getAttribute("comment");` and it'll work just fine and i haven't read anything that says made up attributes harm a web page. unless you're really anal about wanting 100% W3C valid HTML i wouldn't be too stressed by it

Comment: [While there are benefits, Google doesn’t really care if your page is valid HTML and valid CSS.](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/official-google-prefers-valid-html-css/). also it would be really hypocritical if google penalized sites which weren't 100% W3C Valid when [they themselves aren't valid](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)

Comment: Enjoyed your comments.

Comment: Remember these comments are for you now, other devs, and perhaps future-you, in which case it might be best to stick with standard `<!-- html comments -->` which are universally understood to be comments, are easier to see (in most IDEs) and obviously not part of the markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).  Data attributes are designed exactly for what you're intending to do:

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be
>   associated with a particular element but need not have any defined
>   meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on
>   standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as
>   non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or setUserData.

Your div would look like:

```
<div data-comment="start display area">
```

Answer (score 0):

To add custom attributes you should use `data-*` :

```
<div data-comment="start display area">
     ...
</div>
```

Source: [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Another option would be to use [DTD attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_attributes.asp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
 [
  <!ATTLIST tag comment CDATA #IMPLIED>
 ]>
```

As to the downside, the only thing I can think of is that for others looking at your code it may not be as readable, as most are probably used to standard format comments.